# Actor does not stop its children properly?

Tags: scala, akka

I have an actor called `Validator`. The purpose of actor is to validate a message. Every message has its own UUID and every message creates its own instance of Validator by setting an unique name. Actor path for a message with id `17285ed2-ffdb-11e4-a322-1697f925ec7b` looks like so:    `/user/protocols/17285ed2-ffdb-11e4-a322-1697f925ec7b` . Obviously, once message is validated, the actor will be stopped.

Validator has two actors in its hierarchy. Both of them are responsible for different part of message and independent. Here's how they are created:

```
override def preStart() {
    actorOf(Props[IdValidator], "schema-validator")    ! schema
    actorOf(Props[PayloadValidator], "info-validator") ! info
}
```

If I have an exception, the Validator gets restarted according to default supervision strategy and since `preStart` is called on every new instance of the actor class, it attempts to re-create a hierarchy. When it tries to do so, `actorOf` throws an exception saying that actor name is not unique (namely
/user/protocols/17285ed2-ffdb-11e4-a322-1697f925ec7b/schema-validator)

According to the documentation, the process of stopping children is a part of the restart process. Even more, it's done synchronously - runtime will make sure that every child reports its stop by sending Terminated message to their DeathWatch.

Obviously, I can address this issue by removing explicit name of children, but my question is - is it an expected behavior that guaranteed stop of children actors does not really remove them (they still seem to be existent as a part of old hierarchy)

Comment: When you call `actorOf` in your `preStart`, you should be using `context.actorOf` to make sure those new children are started as child actors of the current actors `context`.  If you do that off of `system` then they will not be children.  Can you share the entire actor so I can see what you imported in order to use just `actorOf`?

Comment: @cmbaxter that's what I thought at first, but they seem to be children, based on the name: `/user/protocols/17285ed2-ffdb-11e4-a322-1697f925ec7b/schema-validator`

Comment: Do you override `preRestart` hook of your Validator actor? It's responsible for shutting down children. If you did, it might explain your behavior

Comment: @cmbaxter that's what I'm doing. I have import context._ few lines above

Comment: @VanyaStanislavciuc nope, I don't